Reasoning behind Barr C Coding Standard: Why have white spaces around asterisk in pointer declaration?
The Barr C Coding Standard 2018 has the Rule 3.1e:

The pointer operators * and & shall be written with white space on
each side within declarations but otherwise without a space on the
operand side.

The reasoning given for this rule is rather vague:

Reasoning: In source code, the placement of white space is as
important as the placement of text. Good use of white space reduces
eyestrain and increases the ability of programmers and reviewers of
the code to spot potential bugs.

Is there some more precise reason why I would want to place whitespaces on both sides of the asterisk?
In a declaration I would personally prefer to write the asterisk directly in front of the variable name:
int *pBuffer;

This way I think it is immediatly clear where the asterisk is belonging to. Especially to avoid ambiguity if someone tries to declare several pointers in one line:
int * pBuffer, pReceive;    // pBuffer is actual pointer, pReceive is not

But I assume the Barr people have some real reasoning for their rule. Can somebody enlighten me why this formatting might make sense?

Whitespace is a non-issue here: Correct way is to always declare each pointer separately.

Rule 8.1-a: "The comma operator (,) shall not be used within variable declarations."

Yes I agree, I would not use comma operator in declarations as well. But that does not explain what putting white spaces around * improves. In my current view it just opens a window for bugs to sneak in. I'm all in for a shared standard of formatting, but I would like to undertand the reason behind the rules.

Someone found it easier to read with more whitespace. Those of us that disagree will not follow that convention!

@jusaca, from a code review standpoint, the only issue would be consistency.  Other than that, I agree with @BoP.

I don't agree that this question is asking for opinions - it asks about the rationale behind a certain coding standard. That said coding standard lacks a rationale and states an opinion is a different matter. "No, there is no reasoning behind it" would be one valid answer, although not a very interesting one without adding more details.

First, I have a small issue with the wording in the rule: * in pointer declarator is not an operator; only the * deference operator is, because it actually does an operation.
While I don't know why Barr has that rule, personally I prefer it because of the consistency with more complicated declarations:
// Pointer is clearly visible
int const volatile * const volatile foo = ...;  

// Looks awkward, possibly a typo
int const volatile *const volatile foo = ...;   

Declaring multiple variables within the same declaration is not a good practice, especially when pointers are involved:
int volatile * const foo, const bar; // What?!


Hmmm,  concerning int const volatile order, I'd go with const volatile int * const volatile foo = ...; to mimic the C spec: const before volatile.  Both before raw type (int).  So know it is a compare against const volatile int *const volatile foo = ...;.

@chux-ReinstateMonica My reasoning is that type specifier is the most important part of the declaration, so it's easier to see it fast because it is at the beginning of the line. I think it also reads more naturally when reading from right to left: "foo is volatile constant pointer to volatile constant integer".

Barr C is derived from MISRA C, but MISRA explicitly avoids being a style guide. Barr C has no such restrictions. So this is just a subjective coding style thing: there's no sensible rationale other than keeping the coding style consistent, which does have merit.
The dead horse argument about keeping the star to the right because of comma-separated initializers wasn't even relevant the first time someone made it back in the 1980s, because multiple variable declarations on a single line was always bad practice even back in the days.
Also C allows qualifiers on each side of the * so any argument about "belonging to the type"/"belonging to the object" is questionable. For example we cannot sensibly argue over what each const "belongs to" in the declaration int const const * const const x.
Personally I write the * together with the left item because when dealing with types only, there is no object present. For qualified pointers, it might (subjectively) make sense to write those specifically as *const, not because "the *  belongs with the object" but rather because the const refers to the pointer. So then you might have int*const with no space even.
The most important part here is to pick a coding standard and sticking to it, at least on project to project basis. Mixing multiple coding styles in the same project is error prone.

Great, thank you for that background and your rational, appreciate it.
